# Как в Spring'е получить первичный ключ?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc

Как мне, используя Spring, получить первичный ключ при вставке записи?
все PK у меня типа UUID, и хранятся типа CHAR(36). запросы делаю через jdbcTemplate. Я знаю как получить ключ используя `KeyHolder`, но там используется тип `Number`. А я использую ключ типа String`.

```
public String insertObject(NCObject object) {
        String id = "";
        PreparedStatementCreator psc = new PreparedStatementCreator() {
            @Override
            public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_OBJECT, new String[] { "object_id" });
                ps.setString(1, object.getObjectName());
                ps.setString(2, object.getObjectParent());
                ps.setString(3, object.getObjectType());
                return ps;
            }
        };
        jdbcTemplate.update(psc);
        return id;
    }
```

Comment: аналогичный вопрос на англоязычном stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597477/getting-auto-generated-key-from-row-insertion-in-spring-3-postgresql-8-4-9

Comment: @НикитаГордеев `holder.getKey().longValue();` я написал что `KeyHolder.getKey()` не подходит, там тип ключа Number. А у меня ключ `String`

Comment: Ясно. Есть вариант использовать PostgreSQL, у него есть оператор RETURNING, который возвращает что угодно, тогда в jdbcTemplate можно вызывать метод queryForObject(), дописав в SQL запрос "... RETURNING _fieldname_", где _fieldname_ - имя поля с ключом

Comment: @ЕвгенийТупиков попробуйте вызвать метод `Map<String, Object> getKeys()` у holder, там нет проверки на `number`

Comment: @MrFylypenko почему-то в `KeyHolder` у меня пусто в обоих методах(